# Stream Motion-JPEG live video stream from Express into React

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a IP camera on the server which has a http link to access the live video: `http://ip/video1.mjpg.`

Is there anyway I can stream the **.mjpg** into the React frontend via Express? I have had success of sending normal videos from the server using Express.

```
request(location).pipe(res)
```

Earlier I used to do streaming to the front end with ffmpeg and PHP as backend when I used RTSP link instead of a http link, but now I'm trying to stream directly from the camera via Express to the frontend REACT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try utilizing the native http module on the serverside. When a client will access this route from a React frontend, the server will fetch the MJPEG stream from the IP camera using the http.get method. The MJPEG frames then could be streamed to the client, maintaining a continuous video feed. Something like this should work,

```js
app.get('/video-stream', (req, res) => {
  const cameraUrl = 'http://ip/video1.mjpg'

  http.get(cameraUrl, cameraResponse => {
    // set the appropriate content type for MJPEG streaming
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary'
    })

    cameraResponse.on('data', chunk => {
      res.write('--myboundary\r\n')
      res.write('Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n')
      res.write(`Content-Length: ${chunk.length}\r\n\r\n`)
      res.write(chunk, 'binary\r\n')
    })

    cameraResponse.on('end', () => {
      res.end()
    })
  }).on('error', error => {
    // handle error here ...
  })
})
```

In React you can use something like a video element to display the stream,

```js
const VideoStream = () => {
  const videoUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/video-stream' // Your server URL goes here ...

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Live Video Stream</h1>
      <video width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoStream
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working out :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `<image>` tag to display Motion JPEG.

I don't use React or Express. Test your link in a normal HTML to confirm it can play correctly, (if yes) then change the shown code to match the expected code setup of React.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Test MJPEG playback <br><br>

<img src="http://ip/video1.mjpg" width="640" height="500">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, but the problem is that, i want my express to serve the video source to the front end.

Comment: You're not giving complete information about the problem. Does your `request(location).pipe(res)` not work if requesting from MJPEG stream location? How did you use it as `src=` for a video tag when you say _" I have had success of sending normal videos from the server using Express"_? A normal video is just bytes, your camera stream is just bytes, there should not be a problem...